# When there is a unique Sylow p-subgroup it is normal, does this mean that non-unique p-subgroups are not normal?

Tags: group-theory

While we know that a unique Sylow p-subgroup is normal, is the converse true?  If there are multiple p-subgroups for the same p are they inherently not normal as a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of a finite group $G$ are conjugate (for a fixed $p$ of course), hence if there are multiple Sylow $p$-subgroups then these subgroups cannot be normal subgroups of $G$.

Comment: I thought as much, thanks!

Comment: This (conjugacy of any two Sylow $p$-subgroups) is often presented as the second of the Sylow theorems, as for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Theorems).